# How to see printed text in iOS simulator

Tags: coronasdk

When I run my application in Corona Simulator I can see the printed outputs in console.
If I built it for IOS Simulator there is no message in the console. How can I see the printed outputs in iOS simulator?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you're on Mac, it shows up in the Console application. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730247/where-is-the-log-printed-when-i-use-print-in-corona-engine

Answer (score 1):

No you won't able to see the console of the iOS simulator.

You must build it for iOS device and use xcode to see the Corona SDK print.

Comment: I built it for iOS like you said and than it shows up in the Console aplication like Cixate says.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, the Xcode simulator outputs to the Mac "Console" app.  It's under /Applications/Utilities or it can be gotten to by clicking on the magnifying glass (Spotlight) and typing in "Console" no quote and selecting the application when it shows up.